# symfony2 don't understand the output of unit test

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

i'm new to symfony2, and learning how to do unit test in this framework, i created the php "calculator" and the test class following the tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sym1\blog>phpunit -c app src/AppBundle/Tests/Util/CalculatorTest
.php
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\xampp\htdocs\sym1\blog\app\phpunit.xml.dist

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.00Mb

[30;42m[2KOK (1 test, 1 assertion)
[0m[2K
```

I ran the command, but I don't understand the output, what is the meaning of this output?

```
Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.00Mb

[30;42m[2KOK (1 test, 1 assertion)
[0m[2K
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that you had:

**one test**: which means you have in total one method (name starting with `test`) in all test classes (ones which name ends with `Test`)

**one assertion**: in all of your tests you had one `$this->assert*` call (like `assertTrue`, `assertFalse` etc)

Notice also one `.` (dot) above `Time 0 seconds`. A dot represents test which was successfull (there were no tests failure). More test you have, more dots printed. Dots will turn into `F` in case of failure, `E` in case of error - some more options are possible.

Comment: thx, but there is some unmoral characters appear on the concole "[30;42m[2K"

Comment: this is irrelevant, it might me some encoding issue. This is the place where usually you have time summary - how much time it took to perform your tests